How to Properly Interact with Pool Token Account in a Liquidity Pool Program using Anchor?
I'm working on a Solana program using Anchor that implements a liquidity pool with a  loan feature. The pool is initialized and funded by users (liquidity providers) who deposit assets into the pool. The pool itself is a program-derived address (PDA) with associated token accounts for holding different assets.
I'm having trouble understanding how the pool's token account (pool_token_account) works in the fund_pool function. Specifically, I'm not sure how to correctly interact with this account when transferring tokens from the liquidity provider's account to the pool's account.
Here’s a summary of my setup:
LiquidityPool Struct: Contains a list of assets (mints) and a bump for the PDA.
rust
#[account]
pub struct LiquidityPool {
    pub assets: Vec<Pubkey>,
    pub bump: u8,
}

impl LiquidityPool {
    pub const SEED_PREFIX: &'static str = "liquidity_pool";
    pub const SPACE: usize = 8 + 4 + 1;

    pub fn new(bump: u8) -> Self {
        Self {
            assets: vec![],
            bump,
        }
    }
}```
FundPool Context: Includes the pool, payer_token_account, and pool_token_account. The pool_token_account is created using the associated token program if it doesn't exist.
rust

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct FundPool<'info> {
#[account(
mut,
seeds = [LiquidityPool::SEED_PREFIX.as_bytes()],
bump = pool.bump,
)]
pub pool: Account<'info, LiquidityPool>,
pub mint: Account<'info, token::Mint>,

#[account(
    init_if_needed,
    payer = payer,
    associated_token::mint = mint,
    associated_token::authority = pool,
)]
pub pool_token_account: Account<'info, token::TokenAccount>,

#[account(
    mut,
    associated_token::mint = mint,
    associated_token::authority = payer,
)]
pub payer_token_account: Account<'info, token::TokenAccount>,

#[account(mut)]
pub payer: Signer<'info>,

pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
pub token_program: Program<'info, token::Token>,
pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, associated_token::AssociatedToken>,

}```
Funding Process: I aim to transfer tokens from the payer_token_account to the pool_token_account, and if the mint isn't already in the pool's list, I add it and reallocate space.
rust
pub fn fund_pool(ctx: Context<FundPool>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let pool = &mut ctx.accounts.pool;

    let deposit = (
        &ctx.accounts.mint,
        &ctx.accounts.payer_token_account,
        &ctx.accounts.pool_token_account,
        amount,
    );

    pool.fund(
        deposit,
        &ctx.accounts.payer,
        &ctx.accounts.system_program,
        &ctx.accounts.token_program,
    )
}```
Questions:

How do I ensure that the pool_token_account correctly holds the deposited tokens?
What’s the best way to manage the pool's token accounts for multiple assets?
Is the associated token account method I'm using correct for this scenario, or is there a better approach?
Any guidance on properly managing the pool's token accounts and ensuring correct token transfers during the funding process would be greatly appreciated.

